# Gunicorn module path

Tags: python, flask, python-3.4, gunicorn

This is my app structure

```
project/
  app/
    manage.py
  server/
    gunicorn_config.py
    start_gunicorn.sh
```

This is my start_gunicorn.sh

```
#!/bin/bash

DIR=$( cd "$( dirname "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}" )" && pwd )

CONFIG=$DIR/gunicorn_config.py

source $DIR/../v_env/bin/activate

gunicorn -c $CONFIG $DIR/../app/manage:app &
```

This fails with the messaage:

> ImportError: No module named '/sys/path/project/server/'

I have tried variations of the above, and searched online as well, but I could not find a way to do it. Is this possible? The main reason is because I want my `pid` file under the server directory, its currently set as `pid="server.pid"` inside `gunicorn_config.py`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

gunicorn expects a `module:variable` to be passed as the command line argument, not a path that you're passing (`$DIR/../app/manage:app`).

Is there a reason you want the pid file there? And tangentially, is there a reason to not use supervisor or something similar to run gunicorn instead of `&`?

Comment: I thought so.. The reason I want it under server dir is just cause I thought it would be neater if all the server - related files were under one directory. About the '&', I was not aware I should look for alternatives, first time I deploy a python app.

Comment: Oh, cool. supervisor is pretty straightforward and widely used for deploying python apps.

Comment: Does it provide any significant advantage on a staging system over using `nohup` and `&` ?